# Cannot install Google Play Services in my Genymotion

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services, genymotion

I'm practicing how to use Google Map API for Android development. It appears that my Genymotion needs Google Play Services to run Google Map API. I searched on the Internet how to install Google Play Services, but when I drag the zip file into Genymotion, it always appearing like this:

[image]

I tried as many ways as possible but it still didn't accept, even using different gapps versions. What should I do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the GApps icon in the top-right corner of the window: Genymotion will download and install the right Open GApps package for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Once your genymotion device is launched, just click on arrow bottom (right bottom corner) then click "Install Open GApps" on  and restart the virtual device.